# I'm getting a "[Vue warn]: Error compiling template:" error in my Vue Application when trying to use a custom component

Tags: javascript, npm, vue.js, vue-component

full error;

```js
[Vue warn]: Error compiling template:

Navbar

- Component template requires a root element, rather than just text.


found in

    ---> <Navbar>
           <Home> at C:\Users\admin\Documents\Coding\Websites\Total-
    Response\src\components\Home.vue
             <App> at C:\Users\admin\Documents\Coding\Websites\Total-
    Response\src\App.vue
               <Root>
```

It's not rendering any content on screen though the vue in browser tool detects the Navbar custom component. I think it might be something with how I'm declaring my component but i'm still fairly new at vue. I've looked all over for solutions but to no avail, so any help would be greatly appreciated! 

code;
-main.js

```js
// The Vue build version to load with the `import` command
// (runtime-only or standalone) has been set in webpack.base.conf with an alias.
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import Navbar from './components/Navbar'
import router from './router'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

Vue.component('Navbar', {
  template: 'Navbar',
  name: 'Navbar'
})

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router,
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App, Navbar }
})
```

-app.vue

```js
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <header>
    </header>
    <main>
      <router-view></router-view>
    </main>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'app'
}
</script>

<style lang="less"></style>
```

-home.vue

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <navbar></navbar>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'home'
}
</script>
<style lang="less">
</style>
```

-navbar.vue

```js
<template name="Navbar">
  <div id="Navbar" class="nav">
    <a href="index.html"><div class="logo"></div></a>
    <div class="navButton">
      <center><div class="navButtonIcon"></div></center>
    </div>
    <div class="navpane">
      <center>
        <a href="portfolio.html"><div class="navtile">Portfolio</div></a>
        <a href="packages.html"><div class="navtile">Packages</div></a>
        <a href="contact.html"><div class="navtile">Contact Us</div></a>
        <a href="login.html"><div class="navtile">Login</div></a>
      </center>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'Navbar'
}
</script>
<style lang="less">
  @backgroundColor: #355477;
  @secondaryColor: #23374c;
  @textColor: #000;
  @baseFontSize: 1em;
  .nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: @backgroundColor;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 20px repeat(7, 1fr) 10px;
    z-index: 2;
  }

  .logo {
    background-image: url("../assets/TotalResponseLogo.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin-left: 20px;
    grid-column-start: 2;
    grid-column-end: 4;
    height: 150px;
    width: 250px;
  }

  .navButton {
    grid-column-start: 8;
    grid-column-end: 9;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  }

  .navButtonIcon {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    padding: 10px 0;
    background: url("../assets/navbuttonAnimation.svg");
    background-position: 0px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }

  .navpane {
    position: absolute;
    top: -2000px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
  }

  .navtile {
    width: 90%;
    height: 80px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 10px 0;
    padding-top: 18px;
    background-color: @secondaryColor;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: @baseFontSize + 1em;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: @textColor;
    z-index: -1;
  }

  @keyframes activateNav {
    from {top: -2000px;}
    to {top: 100px;}
  }

  @keyframes activateNavtiles {
    0% {margin: 10px 0;}
    40% {margin: 14px 0;}
    80% {margin: 26px 0;}
    100% {margin: 12px 0;}
  }

  @keyframes deactivateNav {
    0% {top: 80px;}
    99% {top: 2000px;}
    100% {top: 2000px; display: none;}
  }

  @keyframes deactivateNavtiles {
    0% {margin: 12px 0;}
    50% {margin: 18px 0;}
    100% {margin: 26px 0;}
  }

  @keyframes navButtonAnimation {
    100% {background-position: -1440px;}
  }

  @keyframes navButtonAnimationReverse {
    0% {background-position: -1440px;}
    100% {background-position: 0px;}
  }

  .navpaneAnimation {
    animation-name: activateNav;
    animation-duration: .7s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    display: inline;
  }

  .navtileAnimaton {
    animation-name: activateNavtiles;
    animation-duration: 1.5s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  }

  .navpaneAnimationExit {
    animation-name: deactivateNav;
    animation-duration: 1.5s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  }

  .navtileAnimatonExit {
    animation-name: deactivateNavtiles;
    animation-duration: 1.5s;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  }

  .navButtonAnimation {
    animation: navButtonAnimation .4s steps(18);
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  }

  .navButtonAnimationExit {
    animation: navButtonAnimationReverse .5s steps(18);
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  }

  a {
    text-decoration: none;
  }

</style>
```

Comment: Remove the `Vue.component('Navbar', {...})` from main.js, it's redefining that component with a template that's just the bare string 'Navbar'.  The `import Navbar` in main.js is what will bring in the correct component.

Comment: Worked great but now its kicking out a; "[Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined." error.

Comment: @RoyceBirnbaum Which component is it failing to mount?

Comment: The Navbar, But i managed to sort it out with some muddling. Works great, thanks all for the support!